# Closures in Python - executing an inner function?

Tags: python-3.x, closures

Why is this in Python3 executing the inner function?

```
def outer():
    out_var = 1
    def inner():
        inn_var = 2
        res = out_var + inn_var
        print(res)
    return inner

x = outer()
y = outer()
```

The output is

```
3
3
```

Shouldn't it the inner func be executed and the result printed only when executing x() and y()?

Comment: That would indeed be confusing, but fortunately it's **not** the output of the code you've shown.

Comment: You are right. I tried this in this Thonny IDE. I probably didn't saved it corectly. All clear, thanks.